# Do we need to add the files in the debug/release folder to create a setup in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have created a setup file for my Winform project in Visual Studio 2013 but it won't run after the installation. When I use debug or release mode in Visual Studio, it will run.

A closer investigation, I found out that there's lot's of .dll, .config, .cs, .bin, .manifest in the debug folder as well as the release folder. I think they are the files created when I run debug mode or release mode.

Do I need to include all these files from the debug/release folder to the setup file system when I create my setup? Any idea how to check why my app won't run?

Comment: If not the build output, then just what *are* you including in the setup?

Comment: What do you mean by "it wont run"? Do you get any error? What error?

Comment: do you really have .cs files in debug/release folders? something is wrong

Comment: are checking your setup on the same machine or on clear machine?

Comment: melak47, I only include primary output in my setup file system, which I think it's the exe file after we install the app.

Comment: erg, absolutely no error during installation and after installation. When I double click the exe file, nothing comes up.

Answer (score 0):

The files in the Debug folder must not be distributed, it is against the terms of you EULA for Visual Studio.

You need the release files and unless you are running on the build machine you may need some extra dependencies, You will be told about these in the error messages that are displayed.

More than that I can't help you with, because you haven't said what the error is, unless its no error in which case check your shortcut.

Comment: There no error coming out. After I install my app using the setup.exe file, then I double click it the shortcut or the exe file, then nothing comes out. When I build the setup in Visual Studio, no error too.

Comment: Ok something is wrong, but with no error you are going to struggle to debug it.  Can you create a new solution in Visual studio, write a Hello World app that pauses at the end (Console.ReadLine() or fgetc(stdin) depending on you language, build and run in release mode in VS.  Then run it by double clicking on the EXE file in the release folder.
If that all works, build a new installer and install this hello world.  Hopefully you will spot something that's not right with your program, or you'll get a similar fault.

Answer (score 0):

If the Application runs fine in the Debugging Mode of visual studio, then it means that you are not creating the setup file properly. You have to manually add all files that appears in the

> ../bin/Debug

folder of your project to  after adding the primary output.